# Difference between error = error vs error != nil

Tags: swift

I would like to know is there big difference between

`if let error = error{}` vs `if error != nil`? Or is it just how people are different, like how they express themselves in code?

For example if I take this code:

```
user?.delete { error in
  if let error = error {
     print(error)                        
} else {

}
```

Because I can do the same like this and the output is the same:

```
user?.delete { error in
  if error != nil {
     print(error)
}else{

}
```

The only difference I can see other than "people are different" is that if I do not print error it would be better to use `if error != nil` because otherwise it would be declaring variable you do not use. Am I right?

Comment: I would just agree with you, that if I want to use the error to print it out, I would use `if let`. If I would just to check if its not nil and don't need the error variable, I just would use `if error != nil`. But its just an opinion rather than a perfect answer

Comment: Agreed with @ronatory, you already have your answer. Unwrap the value if you need to use it, otherwise just compare to nil. You could also do `if let _ = error` which is the same as `if error != nil` but I prefer the latter, personally.

Comment: Awesome. Maybe add as an answer so I can tick it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already recognized at the end of your question, I would agree with you, that I would use `if let`, if I want to use the error variable to print it out for example. If I would just check if it's not nil and don't need the error variable, I would use `if error != nil`. You could also do `if let _ = error`, which is the same as `if error != nil` as [Eric Aya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227743/eric-aya) mentioned in the comments of your question